# How to select values from temp table and pass them as parameter to SP

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have a SelectSP which returns resultset that i am storing in the temp table. Now i want to call another SP named InsertSP and pass the values from this temp table as parameter to the it.

Here is the code i have so far:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempTable
(
    Field1 VARCHAR(255),
    Field2 VARCHAR(255),
    Field3 VARCHAR(255),
    Field4 VARCHAR(255),
    Field5 VARCHAR(255),
    Field6 VARCHAR(255),
    Field7 VARCHAR(255)
        .
        .
        .

)

INSERT INTO #tempTable exec 
usp_SelectSP 'p1' ,'p2', 'p3'
```

Now i want to execute one more SP and pass Field1, Field2, Field3 of tempTable as parameter to that SP.

I was thinking something like this

```
usp_InsertSP
  @param1 = Field1
  @Param2 = Field2
  @Param3 = Field3

FROM #tempTable.
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to call the stored procedure for a single row, or do you need to call the procedure multiple times, once for each row? Why can't the called procedure just `SELECT values FROM #temp`? The callee should have visibility into the #temp table the caller created.

Comment: i need to call it multiple times

Comment: I cannot change InsertSP. I have pass parameters to it.

Comment: Can you give some clue about what the second stored procedure is doing with the parameters that are being passed?

Comment: It executes some BusinessLogic and inserts data in the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't change the called SP then easiest way would probably be a cursor:

```
DECLARE @f1 VARCHAR(255), @f2 VARCHAR(255) --, ...

DECLARE c CURSOR 
  LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
  FOR SELECT Field1, Field2 --, ...
    FROM #tempTable;

OPEN c;

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @f1, @f2 --, ...

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
BEGIN
  EXEC usp_InsertSP
    @param1 = @f1,
    @param2 = @f2 --, ...

  FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @f1, @f2 --, ...
END

CLOSE c;
DEALLOCATE c;
```

However I strongly recommend you change the called procedure. There is almost absolutely a more efficient way to deal with the data in this #temp table if you can change the called procedure to use it directly.

**EDIT**

Demonstrating that a called proc can see a #temp table created by the caller.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.proc1
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE #t1(a INT);

    INSERT #t1 SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2;

    EXEC dbo.proc2;

    DROP TABLE #t1;
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.proc2
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT a FROM #t1;
END
GO

EXEC dbo.proc1;
```

Results:

```
a
-
1
2
```

Comment: I can try asking DBAs to change the SP. Should i ask them to make conditional insert that if #tempTable exists, do not insert data from the parameters?

Comment: No, what they should be able to do is simply `INSERT dbo.table(col1, col2, ...) SELECT field1, field2, ... FROM #tempTable;` - since the called SP can see the #temp table!

Comment: There are other places from where InsertSP is being called and they pass parameters to it. And i want that to work as well.

Comment: Well you have a couple of options, you could just use the cursor and do this poorly, you could fix all the places where InsertSP is called, or you could create a special version of InsertSP for the more efficient set-based method.

Comment: If i check IF object_id('tempdb..#tempTable') IS NOT NULL, will that affect anything if there are multiple users connected to system with same login information? Just confirming as i know it creates temp table per session.

Comment: No, each user gets its own copy of #tempTable, and they can't see each other's copy. Not true though if you use ##globalTempTable.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

**JUST SHARE THE #TEMP TABLE!!!**

You need to read [How to Share Data between Stored Procedures by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html)

All #temp tables created in a parent stored procedure are accessible to all nested called procedures, see: [Sharing a Temp Table from the article listed above](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#temptables)

from the article:

```
The method itself is as simple as this:

CREATE PROCEDURE called_procedure @par1 int,
                                  @par2 bit,
                                  ... AS
   ...
   INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE #tmp
go
CREATE PROCEDURE caller AS
   DECLARE ...
   CREATE TABLE #mytemp (col1 int     NOT NULL,
                         col2 char(5) NULL,
                        ...)
   ...
   EXEC called_procedure @par1, @par2 ...
   SELECT * FROM #mytemp
go
```